# how to have event listener event click show up an image?

Tags: javascript

How is SetAttribute used? I'm learning JS, and trying to spin-off from a lesson from [30 Days of JS](https://javascript30.com/) to push further of my understanding of JS.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is that any of the "circle" is clicked on, that an image shows up.

I'm just starting to learn JS. Please, please break it down in the simplest terms possible, and not complicated or fancy solutions since they won't do anything to further my understanding of JS.

TIA

Here's my spin-off code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Randomy</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="circles">
        <div data-key="81" class="circle">
            <kbd>Q</kbd>
            <span class="img">clap</span>
        </div>
        <div data-key="87" class="circle">
            <kbd>W</kbd>
            <span class="img">hihat</span>
        </div>
        <div data-key="69" class="circle">
            <kbd>E</kbd>
                <span class="img">kick</span>
        </div>
        <div data-key="82" class="circle">
            <kbd>R</kbd>
            <span class="img">openhat</span>
        </div>
        <div data-key="84" class="circle">
            <kbd>T</kbd>
            <span class="img">boom</span>
        </div>


        <img hidden data-key="81" src="img/icecream.jpg" />
        <img hidden data-key="87" src="img/mini-popsicles.jpg" />
        <img hidden data-key="69" src="img/mini-poptarts.jpg" />
        <img hidden data-key="82" src="img/mini-potpie.jpg" />
        <img hidden data-key="84" src="img/rainbow_ring.jpg" />


    <script>
        document.addEventListener("click", myFunction); 

        function myFunction() {
            var oy = document.getElementsByClassName("circles")[0];
            oy.getElementsByClassName("circle")[0].setAttribute("src", "img/mini-popsicles.jpg"); 
        }

    </script>


    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `setAttribute` works as you implemented. 
The issue here is with the attribute itself that you are setting.

Your elements with class `circle` are divs. Div doesn't have a `src` attribute.

`<div data-key="81" class="circle">`

You have several ways to achieve what you are trying to do. 
For example, you can use images which are not displayed by default (`display:none;`) 
Then on click with JavaScript set the `src` attribute to the one you want to, and display them changing the `display` property.

Otherwise, you can use background-images on the div to display an image inside a div